# When do you and when don't you revert a feature?

Tags: hooks, features

That's basically the question.

Or should I always include this `hook_update_N()` when ever I recreate/update a feature.

```
function my_global_update_7001(&$sandbox) {
  $feature = features_get_features('my_feature');
  $components = array_keys($feature->info['features']);
  features_revert(array('my_feature' => $components));
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not write update hooks for features. To update a feature you modify your content types, views, fields, etc. Once your changes have been made you recreate the feature. When you push your new feature to another environment (dev, qa, live) that has a different version of the database, (i.e. the changes you just made) you use revert to update the environment.

Comment: The question is about doing the feature revert in the update hook. It's a good practice to use.

Comment: @cleaver Ah, I must have missed that. I am still not sold on the 'good' practice though, especially if you revert. How would you be sure to not override another developers changes in a dev environment (possibly live environment but that would definitely be bad practice on their part). Just wondering because I can see the use if you could.

Comment: There's no right answer of course, as it depends on the development workflow. However, if you automate the deploy to an integration server and run automated tests, you should catch the conflicts. As well, Feature conflicts would mostly be caught when merging changes.

Answer (score 1):

Often I find that the feature needs to be reverted, but it's not 100% predictable. I do as you suggest and revert the feature in the update hook whenever there's a change. You never know if an update to Features module will affect when you can get away without reverting.

The alternative would be to do `drush fu all` in a deploy script.